# Style jQuery ajax returned data to look like chips in the input box

Tags: jquery, css

The jQuery ajax call return results based on search term. One user select the result, they appear in the text box as plain text. I want them to appear as chips. So that if someone selects multiple values from the result, multiple chips will appear.

Here is my jquery ajax call:

```
success: function(res, status, responseHeader) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'GET',
                beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    jQuery($id).autocomplete({
                        source: function(request, response) {
                            jQuery.ajax({
                                url: url,
                                success: function(data) {
                                    var parsedPayload = JSON.parse(data.payload);
                                    data = parsedPayload;
                                    response(jQuery.map(data, function(item) {
                                        console.log("Label is: ",item.label);
                                        console.log("Value is: ", item.value);
                                        return {
                                            label: item.label,
                                            value: item.value
                                        }
                                    }));
                                }
                            });
                        },
                        minLength: 3
                        });
                    },
                    error: function(data) {
                        console.log("Failed);
                    }
                });
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a default css for chips. How you want to add these to your page is up to you, but here is the css and jQuery to manage them.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.chip button', function() {
    let id = $(this).closest('.chip').data('id');
    console.log(`removed chip ID ${id}`)
    $(this).closest('.chip').remove();
  })

  $('[data-chipmaker]').click(function() {
    let v = $('input#chipmaker').val();
    if (v.trim() !== '') {
      $('.chips').append(`<div class="chip" data-id='_TBD_'> <div class="chip__content">${v}</div><button class="button">X</button></div>`);
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.chip {
  align-items: center;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-radius: 9999px;
  padding: 4px 4px 4px 8px;
}

.chip__content {
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='chipmaker' placeholder="Type in a new chip" /> <button data-chipmaker>Go</button>
<hr>
<div class='chips'>
  <div class="chip" data-id='1'>
    <div class="chip__content">Chip 1</div>
    <button class="button">X</button>
  </div>

  <div class="chip" data-id='2'>
    <div class="chip__content">Chip 2</div>
    <button class="button">X</button>
  </div>

  <div class="chip" data-id='3'>
    <div class="chip__content">Chip 3</div>
    <button class="button">X</button>
  </div>

  <div class="chip" data-id='4'>
    <div class="chip__content">Chip 4</div>
    <button class="button">X</button>
  </div>
</div>
```